# How to resolve Importing a file from blender in its exact apperance to unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, boolean, blender

I am wanting to create cards for unity, I'm using Blender to achieve this (this is what it looks like: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ypU.png)). when I import through to unity, I get this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNUPz.png)

now I am aware that I have hidden a cube, though that cube was used as a boolean for one of the other shapes.

I find that even if I move the cube object in unity that there are different results (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCm8W.png). Is there a way to have the import be the exact same from blender with having the selected object hidden?

Comment: Your problem is related to the light , materials , shader you're using that's why you get such result

Comment: I am also curious why the bottom of the "lightbulb" icon is only showing parts of it - Also i am not that worried about the lighting situation

Comment: I am finding that the top showing sides of the cap section of the "lightbulb" are not showing, both in scene and game view, I go and load it up (from unity) in 3D viewer and there isn't an issue